# windows 7 drivers compatible with ubuntu in lenovo ideapad s100?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, lenovo, compatibility

I am planning to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo Ideapad S100 with the following specifications:

- Intel atom CPU N570 1.66GHz
- 1.67 GHz 2GB RAM.

I only have the required drivers for Windows 7 32 bit.

Will my windows 7 drivers work in Ubuntu? Do I also need drivers for Ubuntu? In case I need drivers, where should I get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 drivers and Ubuntu drivers are completely different so no you cannot use your Windows drivers. However when you install you will have the required drivers automatically downloaded.

If you're worried about hardware you aren't forced to install but you can still check if everything works correctly prior to installing by booting off a live CD or USB: [Try Ubuntu before you install](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) also check if your laptop is listed as [Certified Hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/make/Lenovo/?category=Desktop&category=Laptop&category=Netbook) this should give you an idea of what sort of performance to expect with your hardware.

If you need to install graphics drivers, theres also a helpful step by step guide on the [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto) which could be handy if you'd like to check any issues yourself prior to asking for further help.

Overall I'd suggest you try it out on a live USB and if there are any issues (sometimes there are with wireless/graphics drivers) give the questions on this site a look, as many hardware driver issues are already resolved.

Answer (score 1):

> Will my windows 7 drivers work in ubuntu?

No

> Do I also need drivers for ubuntu?

Yes, but they come WITH the installation of Ubuntu. Most of them that is since there is a bit of hardware that is not compatible with Ubuntu. To check if your system works out of the box with Ubuntu you can use the Live CD part of the installation media.

Your system has been used before by others so you are good to go from what I can tell. I did see some issues with the network card (Realtek) but that was with older versions of Ubuntu. If these still exist you might need to change the software that is used to connect to the internet (network manager) to WICD.

Comment: no problem @MichelleNonato I like 'wasting' my time on AU ;-)